Arabic/Urdu words not rendering properly while generating pdf in Flutter App
final arFont = await PdfGoogleFonts.tajawalRegular();
final urduFont = await PdfGoogleFonts.amiriRegular();

i have used these fonts for urdu and arabic and also set letterSpacin to 0 butt still on pdf preview it displays wrong output.

this is output and i want it to be not separated like characters.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
